Python Requirements file on rhel 8 machine(red hat 8)
I was working on ubuntu desktop and had created a requirements.txt file using pip freeze > requirements.txt but now when I try to install those package on rhel8 I am unable to as it gives me issue:-
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiosignal==1.3.1 

And similar issue for other packages also.
system : rhel 8 
python 3.6.8
pip 21.3.1

I searched and found that python packages that are available for ubuntu are not available for rhel 8. But I need those packages as I have to run my application. What is the possible option?

This is a headless server rhel 8 machine.

If you have more details to add, click on the Edit button and add it to the question.

Python 3.6 went out of support in late 2021. You should probably work against a more modern platform.

Python 3.6 support was removed from aiosignal after 1.2.0, so you might be able to work with that version or a newer Python

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosignal/blob/master/CHANGES.rst
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosignal/pull/267

$ dnf install python3.9

# requirements.txt
- aiosignal==1.3.1
+ aiosignal==1.2.0


Remember to create a requirement file from using a python virtual environment, so that way you can have your packages isolated from your OS python packages.
The first thing I suggest is upgrading your pip via:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

However, looking at the package info on pipy it says that requires python 3.6 or higher, however, in a different section of the same site it says python 3.7 whichs seems a bit confusing.
Also, looking at RHEL 8 documentation here, I find a package named python39-aiosignal included in one of the repositories for Red Hat Satellite. In my case, I've never used RHEL before, but I would suggest to upgrade your python version to 3.9 and try installing the package again from your RHEL distro.
